# Multiple Distinct Values Grouped And Ordered Within A Range

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to figure out how to write a query on Postgresql to accomplish selecting multiple distinct ranges and min values.

This query does not work:

```
SELECT distinct (a.userID), 
    a.id,
    a.serverID, 
    min(a.minTime), 
    a.recTime
from test_table as a where   
    a.id >= 1 
group by a.serverID, 
    a.userID,
    a.id, 
    a.recTime
order by 
    a.serverID desc;
```

(here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3779c/6) that creates the table with data and the above query)

To illustrate the question, I have an example table containing data such as this:

```
id      userID  serverID    minTime     recTime
-----------------------------------------------------
1       foo     120         9.8         1/18/18 12:26
2       foo     120         4.4         1/19/18 12:26
3       foo     119         2.3         1/20/18 12:26
4       bar     118         12.7        1/21/18 12:26
5       bar     120         6.6         1/22/18 12:26
6       foo     118         4.9         1/23/18 12:26
7       bar     119         17.5        1/18/18 12:26
8       tab     118         12.1        1/18/18 12:25
9       tab     119         3.2         1/19/18 12:25
10      foo     120         11.4        1/20/18 12:25
11      foo     120         5.2         1/21/18 12:25
12      bar     120         8.9         1/22/18 12:25
13      foo     118         4.1         1/23/18 12:25
14      tab     119         12.3        1/24/18 12:25
15      tab     120         9.6         1/25/18 12:25
16      bar     119         4.8         1/26/18 12:25
17      tab     118         11.0        1/27/18 12:25
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to select all distinct pairings of userIDs to serverIDs within a range of record IDs (in this case 1..17). And within that group I need to return the distinct record that contains the smallest minTime by server ID for each of those parings. UserID & serverID change frequently, so those can't be hard coded into the query.

The desired result for the query (based on this sample data) should look like this (spaces added or readability):

```
id      userID  serverID    minTime     recTime
-----------------------------------------------------
2       foo     120         4.4         1/19/18 12:26
3       foo     119         2.3         1/20/18 12:26
13      foo     118         4.1         1/23/18 12:25

5       bar     120         6.6         1/22/18 12:26
16      bar     119         4.8         1/26/18 12:25
4       bar     118         12.7        1/21/18 12:26

15      tab     120         9.6         1/25/18 12:25
9       tab     119         3.2         1/19/18 12:25
17      tab     118         11          1/27/18 12:25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3779c/26)**

```
  WITH ranking as (
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userID,  serverID
                               ORDER BY minTime) as rn
     FROM YourTable
     WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 17
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM ranking 
  WHERE rn = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | userid | serverid | mintime |              rectime | rn |
|----|--------|----------|---------|----------------------|----|
| 13 |    foo |      118 |     4.1 | 2012-09-29T02:31:00Z |  1 |
|  3 |    foo |      119 |     2.3 | 2012-09-28T02:31:00Z |  1 |
|  2 |    foo |      120 |     4.4 | 2012-09-28T02:31:00Z |  1 |

|  4 |    bar |      118 |    12.7 | 2012-09-29T06:36:00Z |  1 |
| 16 |    bar |      119 |     4.8 | 2012-09-29T02:31:00Z |  1 |
|  5 |    bar |      120 |     6.6 | 2012-09-29T02:31:00Z |  1 |

| 17 |    tab |      118 |      11 | 2012-09-29T02:31:00Z |  1 |
|  9 |    tab |      119 |     3.2 | 2012-09-29T02:31:00Z |  1 |
| 15 |    tab |      120 |     9.6 | 2012-09-29T02:31:00Z |  1 |
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

using derived table and min

```
select tt.* from 
(
select 
t.UserID,
T.ServerID,
min(minTime) NewMinTime
from
test_table t
group by
t.userId,ServerID
) x
inner join test_table tt
on tt.userid = x.userid
and tt.serverid = x.serverid
and tt.mintime = x.newmintime
order by tt.userid,tt.id
```